# WCF OData Server Exception 500 - What is System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAborted?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, odata

I am working through diagnosing a really hard-to-find problem with a web service I'm supporting. We're seeing exceptions being thrown whenever we do a complex query on our web service. If it's not a fairly unhelpful 400 error code, it's an even less helpful 500.

I've managed to configure error tracing on the service and looking through the activities, I see that in processing an action on one of the executed steps, the description includes

> Aborted 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAborted'

What does this mean and how do I prevent it?

Comment: what does the respective step actually do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can by anything - from some problem opening a DB connection to some weird error accessing some resource via http etc.

Add this to your .svc.cs file `config.UseVerboseErrors=true;` - it could help track it down...

Check the Troubleshooting section at MSDN, it excplictly mentions 400 and 500 error codes similar to your scenario - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192995